# After adding SQLcipher sqlite3_exec returns SQLITE_NOTADB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sqlcipher

I configured SQLCipher as the tutorial in their site... I can compile & Run the project. 
But sqlite3_exec returns SQLITE_NOTADB when trying to execute a statement.

Please find code snippet below:

=================

```
NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];           
if(success) {
    int sql_results = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &SQLDB);            
    const char* key = [@"BIGSecret" UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(SQLDB, key, strlen(key));
    if (sql_results == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *sql;
        const char *update_sql; 
        sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DROP table %@",tablename];
        update_sql = [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(sqlite3_exec(SQLDB, update_sql, nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK) { 
            NSLog(@"Good to go %@ dropped",tablename);
        }
        else {      
            NSLog(@"Bad Delete Cat SQL: %s -- %d", update_sql,sql_results); 
            NSLog(@"error code %i", sql_results);
        }
```

Am not able to get the issue, where I went wrong....

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Cross posting from Mailing list:

> I noticed in your code that you are only entering the block to
>   sqlite3_open if the database file exists. Are you by chance trying to
>   encrypt an existing standard SQLite database using SQLCipher using
>   this code? If so, calling sqlite3_key will not work that way. You'd
>   instead want to open the standard SQLite database, attach a new
>   encrypted database, and then export the data between the two. There
>   are some more details on this procedure here:
>
> http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export
>
> Once you're dealing with an encrypted database you can call
>   sqlite3_key as the first operation before using it.

Comment: Hi Stephen.....
But from the tutorials from SQLCipher ...
Telling SQLCipher to encrypt a database is as easy as opening a database and using “PRAGMA key” or the sqlite3_key function.

#import <sqlite3.h>

...
sqlite3 *db;
if (sqlite3_open(@"/path/to/database", &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
   sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA key = 'BIGsecret', NULL, NULL, NULL);

   if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
     // password is correct, or, database has been initialized
   } else {
     // incorrect password!
   }
}

Comment: Any iOS example, which explains the process?? ... Thanks for guiding

Comment: @Ben861305 that is to create a new encrypted database. It will not encrypt an existing standard sqlite database. To do that you would need to open the original database, attach an encrypted database, and then move the information over.